# Hi-hat Sheet notation

Tags: notation, drums

Would someone help me out with the hi-hat notation here?:

[image]

My theory's a little rusty, I'm thinking it is a foot close of the hi-hat and not a closed strike? I only started learning 6 months ago so it's all new.

Answer (score 6):

The hi-hat is closed (and not hit with a stick - else there'd be a note!) on the first 8th, open (and hit) on the second, etc.    There's some ambiguity whether we should hear a pedal hi-hat note on the main beats. If we DID want to hear 'chink tizz chink tizz...' it could have been notated as below.  (We don't need the + articulations - after all there's no way to play a pedalled hi-hat note except by closing it!)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Drum notation has several variants, so it's not straightforward.

Hi-hat is the x just above the stave, and with an 'o' above it's open, with an 'x' or '+' above it's closed.

So, there seems to be hi-hat played open on the 'ands' of each beat. The 'x' marks can't refer to the hi-hat, as there are rests shown for each.

And then the question is 'how much open?' - that's down to personal choice, but with a rest in between each strike, it's going to be nearly closed. Perhaps even an open strike followed by closing it rapidly by foot. For which I don't know another sign...

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percussion_notation#Cymbals) the foot pedal strike is below the staff, so, if its applicable to OPs example, those are not pedal strikes like they suggested.

Comment: @Legorhin- I didn't mean merely a foot pedal strike -  difficult to describe, but it's an open hit, followed by an immediate close - and it's virtually one sound - or should be! Used in soul music as much as any.

Comment: I understood that part, you are using the stick in that though, so its not just a "foot close of the hi-hat" like the OP suggested

Comment: @Legorhin - the sign for a foot-closed hi-hat is a cross *under* the stave, ith the appropriate stem. So it's not that.

Comment: I said that in the original comment. I think we are just arguing the same thing at this point.

Comment: I don’t think there is any standard drum notation though some are more common. I’d play this by hitting the hats while slightly open on the offbeats and letting it ring until the down beat which is when I’d close the hats (but not hit it with a stick).